# Компилятор не может обнаружить функцию MakeVector

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, итераторы

Подскажите, в чём проблема?

```
using namespace std;

template <typename It>
void PrintRange(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    for (auto it = range_begin; it != range_end; ++it) {
        cout << *it << " "s;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename It, typename Element>
auto MakeVector(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    vector<Element> result;
    for (auto it = range_begin; it != range_end; ++it) {
        result.push_back(*it);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    set<string> langs = {"Python"s, "Java"s, "C#"s, "Ruby"s, "C++"s};
    auto vector_langs = MakeVector(langs.begin(), langs.end());
    PrintRange(vector_langs.begin(), vector_langs.end());
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: А как ему вывести тип `Element`, вы не подумали?...

Comment: Конкретная проблема описана в заголовке

Comment: @Harry Предполагается, что выводить будет функция PrintRange

Comment: Вывести, что такое тип `Element`. Вывод не на экран, *вывод типа*.

Comment: Я вас не понимаю. Что такое вывод типа? Стоит задача создать вектор из любого сета.  Строковый сет в мейне - просто для примера и отладки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто компилятор не в состоянии вывести, что такое тип `Element`.

Можно попробовать так:

```
template <typename It, typename Element = typename It::value_type>
auto MakeVector(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    vector<Element> result;
    for (auto it = range_begin; it != range_end; ++it) {
        result.push_back(*it);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Можно так:

```
auto vector_langs = MakeVector<set<string>::iterator,string>(langs.begin(), langs.end());
```

А можно как-то, как хочет увидеть тот, кто поставил минус, но он не хочет пояснить, как именно :)

Comment: Спасибо, Сработало! А можно для понимания процесса объяснить, что делает команда "typename Element = typename It::value_type>"??

Comment: Объясняет компилятору, как вывести тип `Element`, если он  не указан явно — что это тип значения для итератора стандартного контейнера.

Comment: Вроде бы понял. Оказывается, можно было обойтись вообще без Element и цикла. Вся функция может состоять из "return vector(range_begin, range_end);"

Comment: Может. Но вопрос ведь был в том, чтоб научиться правильно писать шаблонные функции, а не научиться обходиться без них :)